Return max value in a table where there are duplicates (MS Access)
I have a table (2016 New) like that with some duplicates
ID  equipment serial number 
---------------------------
1   1         111
2   2         121
3   3         731
4   1         222
5   1         012
6   2         728

I would have a table with each equipment but only with the greater serial number like
ID  equipment serial number 
---------------------------
1   4         222
6   2         728
3   3         731

I try to aggregate with:
SELECT 
    [2016 New].ID,  
    MAX([2016 New].[Numero di serie]) AS [MaxOfNumero di serie],  
    [2016 New].Equipment, 
FROM 
    [2016 New]
GROUP BY 
    [2016 New].ID, [2016 New].Equipment;

But it doesn't work.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you

Define "doesn't work". For starters, you have a rogue comma before "FROM".

You have no ID/equipment = 1/4, so you will not be able to obtain the expected result.

Your output does not reconcile with raw data. Looks like 1 and 4 are reversed for first record of output. Since seem to need the record ID in output, options: 1) a TOP N correlated subquery; 2) build aggregate query to return Max S.N. for each equipment then join that query to table on S.N. - assumes serial numbers are unique, otherwise compound link on equipment and S.N. Your data sample seems too simplistic for real serial numbers, which are usually alphanumeric values and sorting would follow alpha rules.

Even without "rogue comma", it won't work because ID is unique so including it in aggregate query makes every record unique and nothing is aggregated. If the ID is not important, don't include it.
